# How many websites comply to web standards

Tags: web, statistics, coding-style

Does one of you know where to find statistics on websites using web standards?

I've read multiple books on web standards, all give very unspecific data on how many sites comply to web standards. 
Books like "designing with web standards", "CSS Mastery", "HTML and web standards solutions" all contain definitions like "some", "more and more" and "not nearly enough" without a source for this data.

Of course I realise there won't be an exact number, an indication would be great. I feel like those writers will need to have gotten their data from somewhere.

I would be great if any of you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very good reason that those books you read only provided indeterminate quantities like "some", "more", and "not nearly enough". It's because this type of data is not easily obtainable, not by the authors nor by us on Stack Overflow. Anything you might find would be idle speculation at best, and more likely tainted by some strong personal biases.

Those writers *did* get their data from somewhere, but I can't provide any more detail because this is a family-friendly site. Scott Adams used a similar theme to great success in one of his famous comics:

[image: Next week, a doctor with a flashlight shows us where sales projections come from.]

Fortunately, even if you were able to find this data, it wouldn't be particularly relevant. The decision to comply or not to comply with web standards should not be made based on what everyone else is doing.

Comment: +1 - +10 if I could. McDonald's makes the best-selling cheeseburger in the world. That doesn't mean **I'm** going to cook like that when I make my own! I take pride in a job well done, even if (as it seems) very few others do.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, there won't be any such list available. However, I believe most web developers / designers would have a good 'feel' for how many sites they've looked at conform to all standards - and my hunch would be this number would be pretty low (based on my personal experience).

If you are really keen on figures, maybe take the top [100 websites on the web](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/8562801.stm) and go validate them all. Shouldn't take too long and you'd get a feel for how many conform to at least basic valid (X)HTML standards.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the browsers don't actually follow the standards in the same way, this leads to websites being forced to use non-standard code to ensure a consistent feature set and look and feel. The situation has improved massively in recent years but is still far from ideal.

You also have the problem that even agreeing on what the standards are can take a very long time let alone waiting for everyone to comply. The current pace of development of modern browsers means standards will always be playing catch up somewhat.

Sites such as [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org), [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org), [acid3.acidtests.org](http://acid3.acidtests.org), [html5test.com](http://html5test.com) are great to keep up with the latest cross browser techniques and browser support but attempting to code a website and strictly remain inside a set of out dated rigid standards appears a zero sum game.